# JQuery dialog show HTML content and prevent removing HTML after dialog is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have been working on Single page application for the past few days. One of the problems that I'm facing is related to JQuery dialog box. I would like to display my forms in JQuery dialog box. There is a few different screens and each of them have different form. User will click on Add or Edit button. I'm passing div id and that content should appear in the dialog box. Each div has unique id and each div has different form inside. Here is my code that creates JQuery dialog box:

JQuery dialog:

```
var dialogDiv;
$.extend({ 
    alert: function (message, title, height, width, print) {
        var dialogButtons = {
            "Ok": function() {
                message.hide();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        };

        if (print) dialogButtons.Print = function() {
            $(this).dialog().printArea();
        };

        if (!dialogDiv) {
            dialogDiv = $("<div>"); 
        }   
        dialogDiv.dialog( {
            buttons: dialogButtons,
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            width: height,
            height: width,
            overflow:"auto",
            position: {
                    my: "center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: window
            }
        }).html(message);
    }
});
```

Here is example of my div containers for different forms:

```
//Form 1
<div id="myForm1" class="frmLayout">
    <form name="frmUser" id="frmUser" method="POST" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>User Info</legend>
            <div class="formItem">
                <span class="required" style="color:red;"><b>Required Fields</b></span>
            </div>
            <div class="formItem">
                <label for="last_name" class="required">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ur_lname" id="ur_lname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" />
            </div>
            <div class="formItem">
                <label for="first_name" class="required">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ur_fname" id="ur_fname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" />
            </div>
            <div class="formItem">
                <label for="dob" class="required">DOB:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ur_dob" id="ur_dob" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" />
            </div>
            <div class="formItem">
                <p align="center"><input type="button" name="urSubmit" id="urSubmit" value="Submit"></p>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

//Form 2
<div id="myForm2" class="frmLayout">
        <form name="frmVehicle" id="frmVehicle" method="POST" action="#">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Vehicle Info</legend>
                <div class="formItem">
                    <span class="required" style="color:red;"><b>Required Fields</b></span>
                </div>
                <div class="formItem">
                    <label for="name" class="required">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ur_name" id="ur_name" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" />
                </div>
                <div class="formItem">
                    <label for="model" class="required">Model:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ur_model" id="ur_model" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" />
                </div>
                <div class="formItem">
                    <p align="center"><input type="button" name="urSubmitV" id="urSubmitV" value="Submit"></p>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

...Form 3 and Form 4 similar.

Once user access home page all HTML content is loaded and set to `display:none`. Here is example how this content will be displayed in dialog box:

```
$('input[name="my button name"]').on('click', function formSubmit(){
    var tabID = $('#tabID').val(); //each tab on my home page has unique id. Current tab value is set to hidden field.
    var divID = $('#'+tabID+'Form'); //This line of code will select correct form
    $.alert(divID.show(),'Form Input',800,600); //here I show the content
});
```

Problem with this code is that divID content is wiped out from the page once I close my dialog box. For example I will click on Add button on my first tab. Form 1 will show in dialog box. Once I go to tab 2 and click and show Form 2 then go back to tab 1 and try to click on the Add button I will get blank page in my JQuery dialog box. For some reason previous content is removed from the page.
I'm wondering how I can work around this problem and what is the best solution? Should I some how make a copy of my HTML content before I display in JQuery dialog or there is a better way to do this? If anyone can help or have any example please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use `.clone()`.

Comment: In the first JS where the _.dialog()_ method come from? Bootstrap.js?

Comment: @TonySamperi .()dialog is JQuery function.

Comment: @doutriforce I have tried clone but my div with form in it shoed on my screen. Can you provide any example?

Comment: No it's not. You mean jQueryUI?

Comment: `var divID = $('#'+tabID+'Form').clone();`. Is this what you tried?

Comment: @TonySamperi My fault. JQuery UI Widget.

Comment: @doutriforce I tried that and my div is still set to display none. Here is example: var divID = $('#'+tabID+'Form').clone();
     $.alert(divID.show(),'Form Input',800,600);

Comment: @TonySamperi No, it is not an error. Actual tabID is hidden field and holds the value of the current open tab.

Comment: @espresso_coffee, is this what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/t5j8xjxb/

Comment: @doutriforce That's what I'm looking for. Have you tried to show/hide multiple forms?

Comment: @espresso_coffee, no, not multiple. But it **should** work the same way with any form.

Comment: @espresso_coffee, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t5j8xjxb/2/), with multiple forms.

Comment: @doutriforce have you notice that will create new HTML every time you click on the buttons in the nav bar. If you don't click on the close button that can cause all kind of issues. For that reason I have used dialog box.

Comment: @espresso_coffee, but that's how `.dialog()` works...if you need to delete the dialog being closed, you should just add `destroy` on close event. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t5j8xjxb/3/).

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you generate the Modal each time...
I would do this way:

```
var dialogDiv;
$.extend({ 
    alert: function (message, title, height, width, print, clone) {
        var dialogButtons = {
            "Ok": function() {
                message.hide();
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        };

        if (print) dialogButtons.Print = function() {
            $(this).dialog().printArea();
        };

        if (!dialogDiv) {
            dialogDiv = $("<div>"); 
        } 
        if(clone){
            dialogDiv = $("body").append(dialogDiv);
        }
        dialogDiv.dialog( {
            buttons: dialogButtons,
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            width: height,
            height: width,
            overflow:"auto",
            position: {
                   my: "center",
                   at: "center",
                   of: window
            }
        }).html(message);
    }
});
```

I noticed that UI dialog works with DIVs which are already in the page.
But instead of passing an existing element, you were creating one.
That's in my opinion why you lose content.
With the "clone" param, you can pass true/false, to decide if you want to append a new div in the body. 
So it will be available in the future.

Comment: What should be passed in the clone argument? How different is that from the previous code?

Comment: don't you see where the difference is?

Comment: I see that you have added new argument in the function but there is nothing that tells me how that will affect the construction of the dialog or what i should pass in the clone argument?

Comment: I added the description at the bottom of the answer. Please reload!

Comment: Why send `clone` as parameter, if it should always be true?

Comment: Who said that? Maybe you want to open dialogs and don't save them....anyway if you want I can delete that! :)

Comment: Don't bother, mate. I was just asking.